# What does the mailto beside the sender's email mean?

Tags: email

John sent an email to Tom, who sent me an email, embedding the original email. In Gmail, this is the message Tom sent me:

```
Hi I'm tom.
-----Original Message-----
From: john@example.com [mailto:john@example2.com]
Sent: 1 January 1111 11:11
To: tom@example.com
Cc: mary@example.com;
Subject: Re: subject heading here
```

I wanted to send a message John. I do not have John's email, however from the email that Tom sent me, I can see that John's email is john@example.com.

The problem is that beside `john@example.com`, there is a `[mailto:john@example2.com]`.

So to email John, should I email john@example.com or john@example2.com ?

To rephrase the question, what does the mailto beside the sender's email mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"mailto:" is a [URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto) that indicates that the following text is an email address.  So it helps computers to understand the semantics of the text.

This is in the same way that "http:" is a URI scheme that indicates that the following text is an address of a site that can be accessed using the http protocol.

Most OSs will recognise a mailto: URI and know that if you click it, that your default email client should be opened with a compose window and the text following the mailto: populated in the To: field.  Ie, you click the address and it your email client opens ready to write them an email.

While it is difficult to see exactly why the From: address and mailto: addresses are different, it is more likely that the mailto: is right, and probably stems from a misconfigured email client.

Comment: So do you mean to say that it's supposed to be `From: john@example.com [mailto:john@example.com]`. If that's the case, why put the `mailto` part visible at all if its exactly the same as the `from`?

Comment: Because the mailto: is an indicator to the OS that this is an email address, no matter what the context - it could be on a webpage, in an email, in a document.

Comment: @BeeDee ok I didn't know that this was a basic question..

Comment: @BeeDee You're on the wrong site. SF is for administrators. This is SU.